# An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error)

Tags: symfony, debugging, toolbar, profiler

I have a problem with Symfony . While I'm doing things on my site, every so often I get an error that says " An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar ( 500: Internal Server Error) . Do you want to open the profiler ? " and I do not know what this error is due .

I attached part of symfony log where i'm think is the error.

```
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\DummyException: "" at /var/www/Phenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php line 163 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\DummyException(code: 0):  at /var/www/Phenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:163)"} []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] deprecation.WARNING: Defining the getGlobals() method in the "assetic" extension without explicitly implementing Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface is deprecated since version 1.23. {"type":-100,"stack":[{"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3400,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3361,"function":"initGlobals","class":"Twig_Environment","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3367,"function":"getGlobals","class":"Twig_Environment","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":4616,"function":"mergeGlobals","class":"Twig_Environment","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":4623,"function":"display","class":"Twig_Template","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2931,"function":"render","class":"Twig_Template","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php","line":63,"function":"render","class":"Twig_Environment","type":"->"},{"function":"showAction","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\Controller\\ExceptionController","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/Phenix/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2957,"function":"call_user_func_array"}]} []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.exception". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2016-01-18 07:26:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
```

Comment: Did you tryed to manually delete your cache files, and update your symfony vendor throught composer?

Comment: Hello there! I tried , but after several actions , I still see the same error. Why this error message appear?

Another message appears in the log and I think that is related too.                                                                                                                              

[2016-01-18 15:29:27] deprecation.WARNING: Defining the getGlobals() method in the "assetic" extension without explicitly implementing Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface is deprecated since version 1.23.

Comment: Any update about that?